# Terraform CDKTF Typescript How to set environment variables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, terraform, cdktf

I have the following code:

```js
class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    const awsSecrectKey = new TerraformVariable(this, "aws", {
      type: "string",
      sensitive: true,
    });

    new AwsProvider(this, "AWS", {
      secretKey: awsSecrectKey.value
    });
  }
}
```

I want to read the variable aws from any configuration file. I tried the following:

1. export aws="test"
2. export aws="TF_VAR_aws"
3. Created `.terraformrc` file in `~` with values
4. Used dotenv to add TF_VAR_aws to process.env

How can I add env variables to my configuration?

Comment: Did you `EXCLUDE_STACK_ID_FROM_LOGICAL_IDS` to true? Without this, variables get a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check what the logical id of the variable is, it should be aws, but if you dont have the `EXCLUDE_STACK_ID_FROM_LOGICAL_IDS` flag in your cdktf.json it might be suffixed. Then setting the value to this id should be sufficient. You can check for this id by inspecting the generated JSON after `cdktf synth` ran